# Put multiple custom loops on same page

Tags: loop

I want multiple loops on my homepage, however only the first loop shows up. My homepage looks like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home
*/
get_header(); ?>
        <!--Four Columns-->
    <hr>
    <div id="content" class="twelve columns">

            <div class="post-box">
                <?php get_template_part('loop', 'land'); ?>
            </div>

        </div><!-- End Content row -->
    <hr>

        <!-- Row for main content area -->
        <div id="content" class="twelve columns">

            <div class="post-box">
                <?php get_template_part('loop', 'home'); ?>
            </div>

        </div><!-- End Content row -->

    <!--<hr>
    <div class="tweleve columns.centered">
    <div class="home-title-thoughts">
    <h2>Our Thoughts</h2>
    </div>
    </div>-->
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="home-quote">
    <h3 style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;">&#8220;Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication.&#8221;</h3>
    <h4 style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;">Leonardo da Vinci</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is loop-land:

```
$grids = 3; //Grids per row

global $query_string; //Need this to make pagination work


/*Setting up our custom query (In here we are setting it to show 12 posts per page and eliminate all sticky posts) */
query_posts($query_string . '&caller_get_posts=1&posts_per_page=9');


if(have_posts()) :  while(have_posts()) :  the_post(); 
?>
<?php
//Show the left hand side column
if($counter == 1) :
?>
            <div class="four columns">
                <div class="postimage">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
                </div>
                <h3 style="text-align:center;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>          

<div class="clear"></div>
<?php
endif;
?>

<?php
endwhile;
//Pagination can go here if you want it.
endif;
?>
```

Here is loop-home

```
<?php /* Start loop */ ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!--<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>-->
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<nav id="page-nav"><p>' . __('Pages:', 'reverie'), 'after' => '</p></nav>' )); ?>
<?php endwhile; // End the loop ?>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you referring to the 2 loop templates? You'd need to show the code in those files.

Comment: Please include the `loop` code in your question.

Comment: @vancoder I added the loop codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you used [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) your `loop-land` template is clobbering the main query. [Don't use `query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=don%27t%20use%20query_posts). In `loop-land` do this instead:

```
$land = new WP_Query($query_string . '&caller_get_posts=1&posts_per_page=9');
if($land->have_posts()) :  while($land->have_posts()) :  $land->the_post();
```

What happens is that [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) overwrites the main Loop and you loop over that. When you get to the `have_posts` part of the second loop, the post counter is already at the end. You've already Looped through the posts.